# RNeo4j: Error in httr::content(response)$errors : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, neo4j, r-neo4j

I am new to RNeo4j. I was running the following the codes.

```
library(RNeo4j)
graph = startGraph("http://localhost:7474/db/data", username='neo4j', password='xxxxx2')
addConstraint(graph, "Person", "name")
```

However, I'm getting error after addConstraint(graph, "Person", "name")
Here is the error code:

```
Error in httr::content(response)$errors : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: After reinstalling the package, its working fine. :)

Comment: I fixed that pretty recently. You were getting that because you were missing  the last forward slash in the URL.

Comment: Thanks Nicole for your reply

Answer (score 2):

To give a full answer:

You were getting this error because you passed a URL that did not have a forward slash at the end. And my error handling wasn't giving proper error messages for broken URLs. This was fixed in https://github.com/nicolewhite/RNeo4j/issues/30.

I've also added a few lines to add the trailing forward slash if it's omitted: https://github.com/nicolewhite/RNeo4j/commit/96e1b05a68a44cf2d9224a28bfe40a86f8fcebfb.